# How to login to the Google API via console and make POST and GET requests to work with Spread sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I need to work with Google Spread sheets data via console - read the rows, edit them, delete them, etc. On OAuth 2.0 Playground everything works fine.
The first task, as I understood it, get a token.
The second is how to use token to make a request for editing sheets.
I see a lot of examples how to do this on Node.js, Android, C#, but I do not find it anywhere to do it in the browser by POST/GET or console.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you will need to do is get an access token.  The access token can then be tacked onto any of your requests to the sheets api

```
access_token=
```

The following is a quick reference example of three legged OAuth2  request to Google.
Note: client_id, redirect_uri, client_secret are all values that you have set up for your app in Google Developers Console. Scope will depend upon which Google Api you would like to access, more then one can be separated by a comma.  I will be using the scope for Google Analytics in this example.

The initial URL to request that the user give you access to there account should look like this: Note: response_type=code

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

This will return a Authentication Code, it is used to request a refresh token.   It is displayed to the user in the body of the html as well as in the title of the page. To get a Refresh Token you POST the Authentication code back to Google. Note: This is a **HTTP Post** you cant just place it in a browser that would be a HTTP Get. Note: grant_type=authorization_code

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

This is the response:

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

The access_token you get from the above request is what you will be using to make requests to the service. After one hour your access token will have expired you will need to request a new access_token you take the refresh_token that you got above and **HTTP Post** it to: Note: grant_type=refresh_token

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

This is the response:

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

My full tutorial on this can be found [here](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Answer (score 0):

In the [Google Sheets API reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/), all possible operations with the API are documented. It says exactly which URLs (endpoints) to contact, which method (GET or POST) to use, which parameters to include and how request bodies have to look like.

Comment: Of course, I tried these requests, but they do not work. For example, how to use a token with this?